# PictureBox DrawToBitmap throws an exception invalid parameter

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I'm trying to capture the screen and assign the captured image to a `PictureBox`, do some drawing using the `Paint` event, then draw it to a different `Bitmap` for saving. However, when I do this, I get exception saying *"Invalid parameter"*.

```
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                               PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                             Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                             0,
                             0,
                             bmpScreenshot.Size,
                             CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

// Assign the screenshot to the image
pbScreen.Image = bmpScreenshot;

// Do some drawing here  
//....
//....

// Draw that to bitmap so I can save it with edits
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbScreen.Image);
GraphicsUnit test = GraphicsUnit.Display;
var rect = Rectangle.Round(pbScreen.Image.GetBounds(ref test));
pbScreen.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect); // <-- Exception happens here
```

EDIT: full exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds)
   at app22.fgrab.CaptureScreen() in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\Form1.cs:line 98
   at app22.fgrab.Action() in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\Form1.cs:line 105
   at app22.fgrab.DoAction(HotKeyEventArgs e) in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\Form1.cs:line 67
   at app22.fgrab.HotkeyManager_HotKeyPressed(Object sender, HotKeyEventArgs e) in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\Form1.cs:line 59
   at app22.HotkeyManager.OnHotKeyPressed(HotKeyEventArgs e) in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\HotkeyManager.cs:line 48
   at app22.fgrab.WndProc(Message& m) in D:\CProgramming\app22\app22\Form1.cs:line 122
```

Comment: Does the exception have any more details than just "invalid parameter"?

Comment: @cubrr I added the full exception

Comment: The code you have posted works just fine when called form a button click and a freshly added pbox.  Try it!  - Is there anything funny with the 1) picturebox? 2) drawing?? or 3) the hotkey?

Comment: Please show us the paint event!

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful world of GDI+ error messages. This message can mean a lot.

I see one big problem with your code: none of the types implementing [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) actually get disposed. This would be [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx).

You have two possibilities to dispose them:

1. Use them in a `using` statement:

   ```
   using(var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(...)) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Of course, not just `bmpScreenshot`, but every variable of a type implementing `IDisposable`.
2. Dispose them yourself using [`.Dispose()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) when you don't need them anymore.

Why doesn't the GC kick in?
Because Bitmaps and other types in `System.Drawing` use unmanaged ressources!

Comment: 1) Why would that throw upon drawtobitmap?  2) we do not see the full code. He may well dispose later..

Comment: @TaW 1) because it's gdi+. i encountered the exact same behaviour once myself and got it to work by disposing all the images. 2) i doubt it, but if OP does i will happily delete my answer.

Comment: 1) No. The very code posted woks fine here. 2) That may be so or maybe not.. That being said: All you wrote is true and good to know for the OP, just not helpful in the context of the question. I suspect the Paint event..

Comment: @TaW 1) Just because it works for you does not mean it will work in every scenario. As i said, i had this exact exception once and a small code example wasn't able to reproduce it - but correct disposing fixed it. That being said: I get your point and I think we are both quite right. I only wrote this answer because I encountered this problem a while ago and fixed it like I wrote.